# Weird Keyboard behavior on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard

Since today afternoon my keyboard is acting weird.

Pressing left-shift once gives me 'm' on screen, for certain keys say 'q' if i try to simultaneously press it with shift, I do get a captial letter. BUt for somE keys like 'u', it wont jUst work.

Moreover somE alphabets come capital on their own. Like my text above is.

I tried booting into live cd of an old ubuNtU disc I had, its the same there. So its not a problem with Lucid maybe.

The keyboard is in perfect condition, I dint spell anything on it. It was perfect till today afternoon. I am stumped !

Comment: Have you looked in System -> Preferences -> Keyboards, under the layouts tab? or maybe Keyboard shortcuts?

Comment: Tried that, the layout is perfect. Its USA.

Comment: External keyboard works perfectly, will cleaning the keyboard solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be hardware related.